# Pagination for CoroutineCrudRepository

Tags: kotlin, spring-data, kotlin-coroutines, spring-data-mongodb

I use kotlin coroutines in my Spring Boot project and I access MongoDB using Spring Data.

Everything works fine e.g. for `findAll()`, but when I use pagination, Spring throws an exception on startup

```
IllegalStateException: Method has to use a either 
multi-item reactive wrapper return type or a wrapped Page/Slice type.
```

My code is as follows:

```kotlin
@Repository
interface CoroutinesActivityRepository : CoroutineCrudRepository<Activity, String> {
    suspend fun findAllOrderByTitle(page: Pageable): Flow<Activity>
}

data class Activity(val id: String? = null, val title: String)
```

Is it possible to apply pagination for `CoroutineCrudRepository` ?
The only way that worked for me, was to use `ReactiveMongoTemplate`

```kotlin
@Component
class CoroutinesActivityRepository(
   private val mongoTemplate: ReactiveMongoTemplate
) {
    suspend fun findAllOrderByTitle(page: Pageable): Flow<Activity> =
        mongoTemplate.find(Query().with(page), Activity::class.java).asFlow()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's pretty late, but for future reference...

Try the same, but removing `suspend`:

`fun findAllOrderByTitle(page: Pageable): Flow<Activity>`

If this solved the error, but Pagination is not working properly, you can always use `@Query`. Again, don't use `suspend`.

To use `@Query` to manually achieve pagination, you can use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`. For example:

```
    @Query("""

        select * from table limit :size offset :offset

    """)
    fun findAll(offset: Int, size: Int): Flow<DataClass>
```

To calculate `offset` from `page` and `size` variables:

```
val offset = size * (page - 1)
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
@GetMapping("/student")
suspend fun getStudents(
    @RequestParam offset: Int,
    @RequestParam limit: Int
) =
    ListResponse.success(
        studentRepository
            .findAll()
            .drop(offset)
            .take(limit).toList()
    )
```